# Why do I get a 403 - Unauthorized for any page in my Windows hosted WordPress?

Tags: iis, http, wordpress

I installed WP via the Web Platform Installer (because numerous other efforts had already failed), and after some shakiness, I have it running at least, but of the few starting URLs I've tried, I get a HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized.

I have another copy of WP running locally that works, but I was battling to integrate it into IIS 10 for debugging. I thought WPI would do that nicely, and it is probably done, but now this.

What could be causing this? I have given the `IIS_IUSRS` group full permission over the physical directory, and I personally own the directory, how are these marked as "unauthorized"?

Answer (score 1):

Please clear 'pass-through authentication' in IIS Manager.  Press connect as, provide a user credential with read, write and execute privileges to the folder where wordpress is installed.  Test settings... Both Authentication and Authorization shall have green arrow in the left.  Restart the site and web server.
Did this solve the problem?